# How to resolve "local edit incoming delete upon merge" when SVN do a separated merge

Tags: svn

As we know, when you edit a file in your working dir, and this file was already deleted by others, if you do a merge , you will get "local edit incoming delete upon merge", but how about the following situation?

Some days ago, I merged a specific revision **1000** from branch to Trunk, today, I need to merge revision **990~1100** from the branch to Trunk, you know, the svn merge **990~999** first, then merge **1001~1100**.
In these revision,  directory A has some interesting changes:

**-->** Some files were changed in revision **994** in directory A(the first merge apply these changes)

**-->** Directory A was deleted in revision **1004**(the remaining merge apply the deletion)

At the end, I got a Tree conflict "local edit incoming delete upon merge", I want the both changes can be applied in Trunk, how should I do? Mark the conflict as resolved, then delete directory manually?

Answer (score 0):

Answer my question, maybe someone will encounter it in the future.

I tried some test, and the way to solve this issue is **"Mark the conflict as resolved, then delete directory manually"**:)